# Uniqueness of powers mod n

Tags: number-theory

I was doing this problem

> Let n be a positive integer with $n ≥ 3$. Show that $n^{n^{n^{n}}}-n^{n^{n}}$ is divisible by $1989$.

The answer considered the expression mod $9$, $13$, and $17$. For mod $9$, when $3 \vert  n$ it is true; for $3\nmid n$, by Euler's theorem the answer took the exponents mod $6$ and said that $n^{n^{n}}\equiv n^n (\mod 6)$.

I was wondering why you can assume that the exponents are necessarily equal mod $6$. After all, couldn't there be a case where $n^{n^{n}}\not\equiv n^n (\mod 6)$ but $n^{n^{n^{n}}}\equiv n^{n^{n}} (\mod 9)$?

Also, is there a rule that dictates whether $x^n$ is unique mod $m$ for coprime integers $x, m$, x is taken mod $m$ and $n$ is taken mod $\phi(m)$? For example, $2^n$ mod $7$ isn't unique since $2^1 \equiv 2^4$ $(\mod 7)$ and $1\not\equiv4 (\mod 6)$.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first part of the question,

either n is even or odd. If n is even, so are $n^{n^n}$ and $n^n$. If n is odd, both are odd. So they are congruent mod 2.

If $n \equiv 0 \mod 3$. Then both expressions are 0 mod 3.

If $n \equiv 1 \mod 3$. Then both expressions are 1 mod 3 because 1 to any power is 1.

If $n \equiv -1 \mod 3$. Then both expressions take -1 to an even power, or both to an odd power. So either both expressions are 1 mod 3, or both expressions are -1 mod 3.

So in all cases, the two expressions are congruent mod 3.

So using the chinese remainder theorem they are both congruent mod 6.